# Is there a way to "migrate" an existing MySQL database used with Wordpress to Azure Blob storage?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been searching up and down the internet, and I did see how you could use Azure's Blob storage for storing Wordpress data, but is there a way to take an existing MySQL database that already has my Wordpress data, and move it over to Blob storage in Azure?

Comment: ***Not really an answer*** but I have been working with a few students where they've developed an **Open Source WordPress plugin** to take a backup of a WordPress site (DB and Files) in Windows Azure Storage. The plugin copies the MySQL DB data into Windows Azure Table Storage and the files into Windows Azure Blob Storage. I think this plugin would be of some help to you. We're currently in the process of cleaning up the code and making it available on Github. I will be glad to share more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike, you could create a Clear DB through New -> Store menu in Windows Azure Management Portal. Clear DB is the Microsoft`s partner to provide MySQL. Another option, you could create a Virtual Machine and install MySQL.

Comment: I actually use ClearDB for the MySQL Wordpress database.  I'm limited to 10mb though, for the free version.  So, my thought was to take that and move it to blob storage (much, much cheaper).